# How to integrated Housing ads using admob for eclipse or android studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

How to integrated Housing ads using Admob for eclipse or android studio ,any sample code for latest SDK eclipse or androidstudio

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code in my project and it is working fine. so you can make changes according to your project requirements. I hope it will be work for you. You can make changes banner ad unit code.

**Activity Code**

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String ADMOB_APP_ID = "ca-app-pub-###################~##########";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this,ADMOB_APP_ID);

        AdView mAdView1 = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView1);
        AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView1.loadAd(adRequest1);

}
```

**Activity XML Code**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView3"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="46dp">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**String XML Code**

```
<resources>
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_1">ca-app-pub-################/########</string>
</resources>
```

**Build.Grandle(Module App) Code**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.amazon.android:mobile-ads:5.+'
}
```